# Changing to another DB

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I want to create a copy of my current Apostrophe project, but also want that copy to use a different DB already populated.

How can I change the DB details so that **my Project Copy** uses **DB2**?

Thanks!
D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in `app.js` the `shortName` you've specified is the name of your mongo DB. In your copy change the `shortName` to `db2`

edited for proper case, ty boutell

Comment: I think it's `shortName`, you might want to check case and edit that in your answer.